# When apply the mirror modifier when rigging a character

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to make a character, rigged it, and now i'm adding shape-keys.

question: When is generally the appropriate time to apply the mirror modifier when making a character?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You'd better apply before rigging or shapekeying:

- Rigging: It's always simpler to apply the *Mirror* modifier in my opinion, as you'll avoid bad surprises later on, even though you should be able to keep it in theory. If you keep it, as reminded [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206828/having-problems-with-the-rigging?noredirect=1#comment348838_206828) by Nathan, don't forget to put the *Mirror* modifier above the *Armature* modifier and enable its *Vertex Groups* option.
- Shapekeys: You won't be able to apply the *Mirror* if you've created some shapekeys, so you'll have to recreate your shapekeys.