# Having problems with the rigging

Tags: modeling, rigging

I'm currently trying to make a 3d character for my portfolio to get into an art school, and I'm running into a problem.

I'm trying to rig my character so that I can animate him walking, however, I run into two problems:

1. The hand on one side of my character moves when I adjust the other side's hand, and the rig for that side doesn't adjust with the rig as well.
   [image: My character's Right Hand becomes extremely wonky, while the left hand moves how you expect it to.]
2. The feet of my character does not move properly with the rigging, instead warping drastically as I try and move it. The wings of this character also warp as well, but I think that's because Blender is trying to grip onto anything within the foot's range.
   [image: The character's feet warp when I move the foot rig, and fails to actually move the foot properly.]

EDIT: Here's my file if you want to look at it: [image]

Comment: Hello, pleaase share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=b9gLqzNn" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/b9gLqzNn/)

Comment: You have a lot of issues.  1) put mirror modifier before armature; 2) re-enable vertex groups on your mirror modifier; 3) fix your normals and reweight.

Comment: @Nathan so you should write it as an answer I guess  ;)

Comment: Hah, I'll try it out first before I make it an answer. Now, onto fixing my normals.

Comment: @moonboots if i write it as an answer, i get crap from people who want SE to look all pro and shit when it's not worth the effort for stuff like this.  If I can fit it in a comment, I can help peeps out without having to worry about SE anal retentiveness.  Well, usually.

Comment: ah ah ok......  ;)